# Lie with or rest with

Tags: word-difference

I'd like to ask if there is a difference between these verbs in terms of meaning, formality etc. in the following sense. Can you change the words between the sentences so as to see if they are interchangeable, please.

***To lie with***

To be somebody’s duty or responsibility.(formal)

> It lies with you to accept or reject the proposals.

http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/lie-with

---

***To rest with***

If it rests with somebody to do something, it is their responsibility to do it. (formal)

> It rests with management to justify their actions.

http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/rest-with?q=rest++with

Comment: Argh, I wish people on ELU would put this much thought and effort into their "what's the difference between A & B" questions. +1 out of pure envy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same meaning in this context, but different etymological origins which have long since lost their significance.

Lie came from the latin word *lectus* (a bed) via german *liegen* (to lie). Rest came from the latin word *restare* (to remain), via french *rester* (to remain).

Answer (score 1):

As @JavaLatte points out in your examples both phrases have the same meaning, outside of your context they can have fairly different meanings.

Another phrase which is similar to both of yours (in your context) is

> **leave it with**
>
> **Leave it with** me.
>   *I will be responsible for it.*
>   *I will take care of it.*
>
> **Leave it with** management.
>   *Let management decide*